# Mark reputation changes as read on profile when viewed via the new Top Bar Achievements drowndown

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

When your reputation changes on one of the StackExchange websites you now get a nifty little notification on the 'Top bar'.

[image: Top bar reputation notification]

[image: Programmers.stackexchange profile screen]
 <-- Will still show the red background color even though I already visited the Rep changing question/answer

*( I don't have screens available with the actual green blob on top bar / rep notification on user profile )*

My request is, that when you follow up on that 'reputation change event', as in, going to the question / answer that caused the event, by clicking on the link inside the rep dropdown of the topbar, that the reputation change is marked as 'read' on that StackExchange website as well, so that the red background thingie on the Rep tab in user profile is no longer lit up.

Comment: No, I *like* having the separate views. Especially when you are active on different SE sites, it is easier to look at an individual profile and see the score increase there *for just that site*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters and I like to get the notifications to go away after I've seen the information *once*. I don't like the site reminding me twice about the same *trivial* information. The new top-bar shows per-site reputation changes as well.

Comment: The achievements drop down shows reputation gained only for today.

Comment: For me, Stack Overflow gains drown out other sites; the per-site separate tab is enormously valuable to me.

Comment: I must confess that I am finding it *extremely annoying* to end up reviewing the same reputation changes twice. If my use of the SE network wasn't so heavily biased toward a single site that I view daily, I might derive more value from the distinction between the notifications in the topbar and my profile (as @Martijn describes), but as things stand this is really getting *very frustrating indeed*.  I **BEG** of SE developers to take heed and offer some solution. Perhaps a choice? Perhaps topbar doesn't highlight for notifications on the current site? There must be a better solution than this!

Comment: Devil's advocate here: any reason you can't just ignore one of the two locations if you don't like seeing them twice? The slight yellow highlighting on the profile page is so simple to ignore..

Comment: @mhlester and how about a red highlighting on an otherwise blue site? It's annoying and you want to click it, even if the only reason is to stop it from highlighting, not to mention times when you're getting lots of upvotes in a short while. It's just pointless to acknowledge them in both places.

Comment: @mhlester: I often visit my SO profile (to access, for example, my recent activity) whereupon I see a big notification of new rep updates.  I want to clear that notification, as it relates to things about which I am already aware (having previously reviewed them from the top-bar) - but the only way to do it is to click on the "reputation" tab.  Certainly I could (and often do) then ignore the ensuing highlighted posts, but that is already an entirely pointless extra click that I needn't have done.  Plus it is actually difficult not to give at least a cursory glance over the highlighted posts.

Comment: I can't describe how depressing it is that no member of the SE team has deigned to comment on this question, let alone provide some sort of answer.

Comment: @eggyal I'm sure our overlords will come by eventually to grace use with their presence!

Comment: If the bump of a +500 bounty doesn't help, I don't know what will.

Answer (score 1):

I propose the following:

Only show the highlighting in the profile if a rep gain/loss gets pushed out of the achievement dropdown before looking at it. Very similar to chat mentions, which only appear in your notifications if not signed as seen by replying or clicking the icon.

This would stop it from annoying you unnecessarily while still ensuring you are informed of your rep changes.

Comment: I don't know whether this is the "best" solution, but it'd certainly be better than the status quo.  +1